Permesso di Soggiorno - Time Frame
I wanted to know if the 8 days for issuing the permesso di soggiorno are counted as soon as I arrive to Europe or from when I arrive to Italy since I have planned to visit some family before going to Italy and my flight arrives at France.
Thanks
